# Lisp program is throwing input stream error

Tags: lisp

I get an error that states:

```
***** - READ: input stream #<INPUT BUFFERED FILE-STREAM CHARACTER #P"p5.lisp" @49> ends within an object. Last opening parenthesis probably in line 1.**
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

```
(defmacro mac (start end)
  `(progn
     (defparameter *start* ',start)
     (defparameter *end* ',end)
     (defparameter *visited* '())

 (defun valid-state-p (state)
   (let ((m (car state)) (c (cadr state)) (b (caddr state)))
     (and (>= m 0) (< m 3) (>= c 0) (<= c 3) (member b '(I r)))))

 (defun goal-state-p (state)
   (equal state *end*))

 (defun move (state dm dc)
   (if (equal (caddr state) 'I)
       (list (- (car state) dm) (- (cadr state) dc) 'r)
       (list (+ (car state) dm) (+ (cadr state) dc) 'I)))

 (defun legal-moves (state)
   (let* ((m (car state)) (c (cadr state)) (b (caddr state)) (moves '()))
     (when (equal b 'I)
       (when (and (>= m 2) (>= c 0))
         (push (move state 2 0) moves))
       (when (and (>= m 1) (>= c 0))
         (push (move state 1 0) moves))
       )
     (when (equal b 'r)
       )
     (remove-if-not #'valid-state-p moves)))

 (defun dfs (state path)
   (if (goal-state-p state)
       (reverse path)
       (if (member state *visited*)
           nil
           (setf *visited* (cons state *visited*))
           (dolist (next-state (legal-moves state))
             (let ((result (dfs next-state (cons next-state path))))
               (when result
                 (return result))))))))

(let ((solution (dfs *start* '())))
  (if solution
      (dolist (step solution)
        (format t "~a ~a ~a~%" (car step) (cadr step) (caddr step)))
      (format t "nil")))
(mac '(3 3 l) '(0 0 r))
```

I am not sure how to fix this issue. I am using GNU Common Lisp as my compiler. I need help fixing this error

Comment: You're probably missing a closing paren somewhere. Use an editor with an autoindent feature (emacs or vim according to taste) to review the actual structure of your program.

Comment: After adding formatting it becomes clear that there's a missing parenthesis at the end of the `mac` macro. Also, do you intend to be double-quoting `*start*` and `*end*`? Because you add quotes in both the definition of `mac` and its invocation. Perhaps `mac` should just be a function.

Answer (score 1):

First you one need to post the question correctly formatted. The code should be formatted. Look at your question are improve the formatting of the code.

If you look at your code, it is missing a parentheses. It has one more opening than closing parentheses.

Writing the code as a huge macro also does not make any sense. You should remove the macro `mac` and rewrite the code without it.